# Reading src of an iframe from a text file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to read a text file locally, which has a url for eg.www.google.com and pass this string as a src to an iframe. But the problem is that the src got appended with this:

```
//localhost/myfolder/%25/www/google.com
```

where `localhost/myfolder` is the path of the file in which I am using the iframe.

Thanks in advance if anybody can help me out.

```
function read() 
   {
   var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
   txtFile.open("GET", "http://localhost/myfolder/Text.txt",true);
   txtFile.onreadystatechange = function () 
   {
   if (txtFile.readyState === 4)
{  
   // Makes sure the document is ready to parse.
   if (txtFile.status === 200)
{  
   var alltext=txtFile.responseText;
   var linetext=txtFile.responseText.split("\n");
var delimeter = '^';
var text0= linetext[0];
var splitted = text0.split(delimeter);
$('#iframe1').attr('src', splitted[1]);
   }
   }
   }
   txtFile.send(null)

   }
```

i am using this code to read the file.

Comment: Just put `http://` before it.  It thinks www is a local resource.

Comment: @archer i have tried that also..still not working..even if i give an http://178.125.65.25/../../..filename than also it appends the same thing

Comment: So you have *some code* which you want to do X but actually does Y. It's *really* hard to tell why it doesn't do X when we can't see it!

Comment: where are you testing it. on live server or local server?

Comment: And what is the value of `splitted[1]`? Use a debugger, or `console.log` or `alert` to find out.

Comment: i have checked the value of splitted[1]..its same as the url..but when i check this alert(document.getElementById("iframe1").src)..it gives me the appended string..as http//localhost/myfolder%25/http//www.google.com

Comment: What is it exactly? Telling us that it is the same as something we can't see doesn't tell us much.

Comment: i mean that `splitted[1]` has www.google.com in it..

Comment: @Hitesh — Then your problem is as described in NicolaeS' answer. `www.google.com` is a *relative* URL and references a directory (kinda) not a hostname.

Comment: even if i give `http://www.google.com` it doesn't work..

Comment: Define "Doesn't work". Does it still give the same failure state as described in the initial question? Or does it refuse to render it because Google ban iframing their content?

Comment: when i check `alert(document.getElementById('iframe1').src)` it gives me `http://localhost/myfolder/%27http://www.google.com`

Comment: same failure as stated initially

Comment: Given that `splitted[1] === "http://google.com"`, I can't reproduce your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com/" />
```

If you want the  to show a link external to the current page, you need to specify the protocol too (`http://` or `https://`)

Try that out and let me know how it goes! ;)

**Edit**:
See my comment below - I tested it all and pasted the result to **[a Gist paste](https://gist.github.com/nicolaes/5115439)**

**Edit 2** (answering to @Hitesh's comment below) :
I suggest making the setup work **before** inserting fancybox in the equation.
When you have that working, the fancybox setup should be the same, as `fancybox()` creates the `<iframe />` dinamically and inserts it in the DOM.
If you have the basic iframe setup, just be sure to make one of the following:

1. Open fancybox and let it create the iframe. Then replace the iframe's SRC with your content.
2. Replace the HREF of the `<a />` that opens the iframe *before* the fancybox actually opens. You can use the [fancybox callbacks](http://fancybox.net/api) in this matter.

Comment: i have tried that also..but still its not working for me.Check out the code i have posted

Comment: There are also the [cross-domain restrictions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) for JS + iframes.

That means you can not use JS to change the SRC of an iframe to a different domain that the one you are on (e.g. localhost) - 

(you get `Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.google.ro/ does not permit cross-origin framing`)

Comment: Check [this out](https://gist.github.com/nicolaes/5115439) - I pasted all my test code with results and everything in a Gist link

Comment: it seems to be working for your use case..but in mine i want the iframe in a fancybox and want to pass the link inside that

Comment: @Hitesh I replied you in my answer, just to make it clearer. Hope it helps you solve the issue.

Comment: @NicolaeS-`http://localhost/myfolder/%27http://172.31.144.176:8080/mynewpage.html`
This is src what i am getting in alert when i am using same approach for fancybox..where http://172.31.144.176:8080/mynewpage.html is thepage which i want to open in iframe.

Comment: @Hitesh Please insert `alert('URL:'+splitted[1]);` just before the line with `$('#iframe1').attr('src', splitted[1]);` and `alert('SRC:'+$('#iframe1').attr('src'));` after it. Then post the result here.

Comment: @Hitesh Also, you can use [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) to show us your code, just like I did back a few comments.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you made a mistake in url address because %25 is an unused HTML character codes [check it](http://www.obkb.com/dcljr/charstxt.html) for details.

Comment: no the url address is perfect..as if i give it directly in the iframe.src (without reading it from the text file) it works